# Trying to create an application with slide menu, and JSON list with app-UI

Tags: jquery, json, menu, slide

thank you in advance who will help me and sorry for my bad English. I'm trying to create a PhoneGap application with jquery mobile ios devices. The result is not bad but very slow, due to problems in the data-slide transition when data is imported from json are too many. The style used is that of the side menu with slide effect http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html. I have seen the extraordinary results of app-UI, trying https://github.com/triceam/Fresh-Food-Finder the application. I'd like to implement a slide left side menu with three links-style facebook, where clicking on any of them opens a list imported from json, using app-UI, which is definitely faster and more efficient. I tried to implement, but I'm not an ace with javascript, and I'm a little demoralized. Can anyone give me some guideline to follow? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the code of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Demos - Slide Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../../css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../_assets/js/jquery.mobile.demos.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
            <h1>My App</h1>
            <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
            <a href="#add-form" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Panel: Menu + form</h2>

            <p>This is a typical page that has two buttons in the header bar that open panels. The left button opens a left menu with the reveal display mode. The right button opens a form in a right overlay panel.</p>

            <p>Since the panel links are in the top bar, there really isn't a need for the fixed positioning feature on the panel since you will always be scrolled to the top of the page. The fixed positioning impacts animation smoothness so it's off in this demo (<code>data-position-fixed="false"</code>) and the panel will scroll with the page.</p>

            <p>To make this responsive, the left panel stays open and causes the page to re-flow at wider widths. This allows both the menu and page to be used together when more space is available. This behavior is controlled by CSS media queries. You can create a custom one for a specific breakpoint or use the breakpoint preset by adding the <code> class="ui-responsive-panel"</code> to the page container.</p>

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div class="jqm-footer">
            <p class="jqm-version"></p>
            <p>&copy; 2010, 2013 jQuery Foundation and other contributors</p>
        </div><!-- /jqm-footer -->


        <style>
            .nav-search .ui-btn-up-a {
                background-image:none;
                background-color:#333333;
            }
            .nav-search .ui-btn-inner {
                border-top: 1px solid #888;
                border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
            }
        </style>

            <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel" data-theme="a">

                <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" style="margin-top:-16px;" class="nav-search">
                    <li data-icon="delete" style="background-color:#111;">
                        <a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="wai-aria voiceover accessibility screen reader">
                        <a href="../about/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="accordions collapsible set collapsible-set collapsed">
                        <a href="../content/content-collapsible-set.html">Accordions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="ajax navigation model">
                        <a href="../pages/page-navmodel.html">Ajax navigation model</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="anatomy of page viewport">
                        <a href="../pages/page-anatomy.html">Anatomy of a page</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="events api animationComplete transition css">
                        <a href="../api/events.html">Animation events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="listview autodivider">
                        <a href="../lists/lists-autodividers.html">Automatic listview dividers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="button link submit cancel image reset mini buttonmarkup enable disable">
                        <a href="../buttons/buttons-types.html">Buttons</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="button icon">
                        <a href="../buttons/buttons-icons.html">Button icons</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="data-prefetch loadpage domCache data-dom-cache size clear cleanup pagehide lazyload spinner loader">
                        <a href="../pages/page-cache.html">Caching pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="input forms multi select checkbox checks grouped horizontal toggle legend">
                        <a href="../forms/checkboxes/">Checkbox</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="button icon">
                        <a href="buttons/buttons-icons.html">Button icons</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="data-prefetch loadpage domCache data-dom-cache size clear cleanup pagehide lazyload spinner loader">
                        <a href="../pages/page-cache.html">Caching pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-filtertext="input forms multi select checkbox checks grouped horizontal toggle legend">
                        <a href="../forms/checkboxes/">Checkbox</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- panel content goes here -->
            </div><!-- /panel -->

            <style>
                .userform { padding:.8em 1.2em; }
                .userform h2 { color:#555; margin:0.3em 0 .8em 0; padding-bottom:.5em; border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
                .userform label { display:block; margin-top:1.2em; }
                .switch .ui-slider-switch { width: 6.5em !important }
                .ui-grid-a { margin-top:1em; padding-top:.8em; margin-top:1.4em; border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
            </style>

            <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="overlay" id="add-form" data-theme="b">

                <form class="userform">
                    <h2>Create new user</h2>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="status" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true">

                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" data-mini="true">

                    <div class="switch">
                    <label for="status">Status</label>
                    <select name="status" id="slider" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                        <option value="off">Inactive</option>
                        <option value="on">Active</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-mini="true">Cancel</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-mini="true">Save</a></div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <!-- panel content goes here -->
            </div><!-- /panel -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

As you can see, you need to import first your javascript file. Here we need three of them : jquery-min, jquery mobile and jquery mobile beta. All you have to do is to save this 3 js in your project, to import them in your page like the exemple. 
After that, you have to link your button with the script. Like this

```
        <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
        <a href="#add-form" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
```

And then apply some css style to have something pretty nice. If you begin with this, the easiest way to start is to save the page and the js in your project, and play with the code to see how it work.

Hope this help you a little bit ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, really thank you. I have already implemented a similar code in my app. You can see it here http://viaggiosullaluna.it/www.zip. If you try the application on iphone you will see that the slide between pages is slow and if you open the link below does not work (load files via json). Any idea why? Maybe because I do not use a local database? I tried app-UI, you've seen that it is much faster and more functional, but do not know how to implement the code to have the same result :-(

Comment: It happend on iphone, that the jquery is too big and load slowly. To correct this, just keep what you need. I do this with the swipe function to open the menu.I'll check for app-UI

Comment: I have improved the functioning of my app with jquery mobile using http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js. I would say it works better, but I do not understand how you can avoid some things.
Firstly, if I click on a link the page jumps up and then starts the transition.
The second: if I press back, before making the transition, the page do a flash.
I am convinced that app-Ui avoid these things.